# Site not rendering properly on IE8 and below

Tags: internet-explorer, rendering

A few days ago, I updated my homepage with a new design as shown

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8i34.png

The new design seems to be working fine when i tested it on latest version of Google Chrome, Internet Explorer9 and Mozilla Firefox. The site do uses responsive design and also seems to be working on my Xperia Ray.

But in my college, We have Internet Explorer 8 and Internet Explorer 7. So I tried to test the site from my virtual machine with Windows XP, IE7 and site seems to be rendered as follows
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1xQb.png
Something went wrong with it. Please help me to solve this rendering issue.
Direct link for site is

ankurm.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using HTML5 elements. The problem is that IE8 and older doesn't apply CSS styles to unknown elements. You have to register them as follows:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>  
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    document.createElement("header");  
    document.createElement("footer");  
    document.createElement("section");   
    document.createElement("aside");  
    document.createElement("nav");  
    document.createElement("article");   
    document.createElement("hgroup");   
    document.createElement("time");  
  </script>  
<![endif]-->
```

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) ECMAscript library can do it for you.

Comment: Thanks. I used html5shiv instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filtering tags of microsoft to import different stylesheets for the browser that throws errors

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

```
if lesser than msie 9
<!--[if lt 8]>
<style type="text/css">
/* markup here */
</style>
<![endif]-->

if greater than msie 8
<!--[if gt 8]>
<style type="text/css">
/* markup here */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

and that way you can intercept and use different styles. You could also import different stylesheets depending on browser version.

usually it's just internet explorer who hiccups so the conditional formatting should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are using some HTML5 elements. IE8 and below just ignore elements like `<header>` and `<footer>` if they're not registered. Use [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to make IE recognize these elements.

Furthermore, you're using a lot of JS. I don't see how this is necessary for a page like this. I don't know what you use for building the page, but the result looks broken here when I disable JS, which is not nice. It will also be difficult to further debug your problem if html5shiv alone does not fix it.

And lastly, if you're asking something like this, provide a link to your page so that we do not have to read it from your screenshots.

Edit: Oh, you posted it at the very end, but didn't link it. My fault.